# Flutter: Join specific field of JSON file together to become a list itself

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart

I have a json file with a list of different types of data.

I wanted to join the "name" field of all attractions of each city together as a list.
The expected result after joining, for example for Longo city will be like this:

Attraction1

Attraction2

The data in JSON file is structured like this:

```
  {
    "city": "London",
    "attractions": [
      {
        "name": "Attraction1",
        "localrank": 10,
        "intrank": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "Attraction2",
        "localrank": 4,
        "intrank": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "city": "Hong Kong",
    "attractions": [
      {
        "name": "Attraction3",
        "localrank": 10,
        "intrank": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "Attraction4",
        "localrank": 4,
        "intrank": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "city": "Cario",
    "attractions": [
      {
        "name": "Attraction5",
        "localrank": 10,
        "intrank": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "Attraction6",
        "localrank": 4,
        "intrank": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I used the following code, but I get an error :

```
cities.attractions.name.join("\n")
```

Json model class is this:

```
List<Cities> citiesFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Cities>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Cities.fromJson(x)));
String citiesToJson(List<Cities> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Cities {
  Cities({
    this.city,
    this.attractions,
  });

  String city;
  List<Attraction> attractions;

  factory Cities.fromRawJson(String str) => Cities.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Cities.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Cities(
        city: json["city"],
        attractions: List<Attraction>.from(
            json["attractions"].map((x) => Attraction.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "city": city,
        "attractions": List<dynamic>.from(attractions.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Attraction {
  Attraction({
    this.name,
    this.localrank,
    this.intrank,
  });

  String name;
  int localrank;
  int intrank;

  factory Attraction.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      Attraction.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Attraction.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Attraction(
        name: json["name"],
        localrank: json["localrank"],
        intrank: json["intrank"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "localrank": localrank,
        "intrank": intrank,
      };
}
```

And this also calling json file:

```
  Future<String> fetchData() async {
    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data.json");
    final jsonResult = json.decode(data);
    print('$jsonResult oop');
    this.setState(() {
      jsonResult.forEach(
          (element) => Globals.citylist.add(new Cities.fromJson(element)));
    });
    return "Success!";
  }
```

Comment: you should first parse your json to dart

Comment: I have already done parse in dart, but the code is too long to include here. I am able to use all these fields in a listview builder. What I need now is a way to join the text fields of each city attraction

Comment: I suggest just adding the names to a List<String>. For ex: ["Attraction 1", "Attraction 2"]. Then when you want to show it, add "\n" later in between each String

Comment: what I have given is an example, I have very big list of cities and their attractions. I need to do this programatically.

Comment: @ChessMax answer is what I had in mind, check if that help your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
import 'dart:convert';

var data = """  [{
    "city": "London",
    "attractions": [
      {
        "name": "Attraction1",
        "localrank": 10,
        "intrank": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "Attraction2",
        "localrank": 4,
        "intrank": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "city": "Hong Kong",
    "attractions": [
      {
        "name": "Attraction3",
        "localrank": 10,
        "intrank": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "Attraction4",
        "localrank": 4,
        "intrank": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "city": "Cario",
    "attractions": [
      {
        "name": "Attraction5",
        "localrank": 10,
        "intrank": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "Attraction6",
        "localrank": 4,
        "intrank": 5
      }
    ]
  }
] """;

List<Cities> citiesFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Cities>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Cities.fromJson(x)));
String citiesToJson(List<Cities> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Cities {
  Cities({
    this.city,
    this.attractions,
  });

  String city;
  List<Attraction> attractions;

  factory Cities.fromRawJson(String str) => Cities.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Cities.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Cities(
    city: json["city"],
    attractions: List<Attraction>.from(
        json["attractions"].map((x) => Attraction.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "city": city,
    "attractions": List<dynamic>.from(attractions.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Attraction {
  Attraction({
    this.name,
    this.localrank,
    this.intrank,
  });

  String name;
  int localrank;
  int intrank;

  factory Attraction.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      Attraction.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory Attraction.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Attraction(
    name: json["name"],
    localrank: json["localrank"],
    intrank: json["intrank"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name,
    "localrank": localrank,
    "intrank": intrank,
  };
}

class Globals {
  static List<Cities> citylist = [];
}

Future<String> fetchData() async {
  // String data =
  // await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data.json");
  final jsonResult = json.decode(data);
  print('$jsonResult oop');
  // this.setState(() {
    jsonResult.forEach(
            (element) => Globals.citylist.add(new Cities.fromJson(element)));
  // });

  var result = getAttractionsByCity('London');

  print(result.join('\n'));

  return "Success!";
}

List<String> getAttractionsByCity(String value) {
  var result = <String>[];

  for (final city in Globals.citylist) {
    if (city.city == value) {
      final attractions = city.attractions;

      for (final attraction in attractions) {
        result.add(attraction.name);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

void main() async {
  await fetchData();
}
```

It's a working example. You can copy and paste this code to HTTP://dartpad.dev and run it to see the result.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error under cities "error: The type 'Type' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable."

Comment: `cities` is the name of a variable that holds your JSON data. If your variable has another name, just change it.

Comment: Yes, Just change it it is Cities with capital C, but now I get this error "error: The type 'Type' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable. "

Comment: Try to change it like that: `for (final city in Cities as List<Object>)`.

Comment: Now I get an error under `['attractions']` : "error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'."

Comment: Looks like it should be: `for (final city in Cities as List<Map<String, Object>>)`

Comment: Now no error in the code, but when I run the app in the simulator, red screen appears with this error "type '_Type' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, Object>>' in type cast"

Comment: Strange, maybe your Cities don't contain a parsed JSON data? Or it has a different format. I can't say what exactly wrong with this uninformative error. Try to print(Cities) and see what is in it.

Comment: I have included in now in my question, the JSON model class , please check

Comment: Thanks, but your example join the attractions for all cities. I wanted the attractions of each city to be joined. I am actually having two listview builders, one to show list of cities, and then if pressed, another page will show the second listview builder of the attractions of that city. where I need to have a share icon on the appbar to share all the attractions of that city at once. that is why i need to join them first so that they can be shared added to the share button.

Comment: So, you need a list of cities with joined attractions? Like that: London - Attraction1 Attraction2, Hong Kong - Attraction 3, Attraction 4 ... ? Or you need to get joined attractions by city name?

Comment: I need only a list of attractions for that specific city that shows in the second page, for example in the first page, I pressed on London, then second page will show the attractions of London as cards. Now I need to place an icon on the appbar of that page, where I can allow sharing of all the attractions of London at once, one below the other.

Comment: Perfect, it works fine now. Thanks ChessMax for your support, appreciated .